# Power BI: How to convert 20050701(yyyymmdd) to 2005/07/01(yyyy/mm/dd)

Tags: powerbi

How to convert yyyymmdd to yyyy/mm/dd in power bi
[this is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEDhB.png)

I have tried converting to whole numbers and then convert to date date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'Column From Examples' feature in Power Query

Click 'Column From Examples' in Add Column and type 2005/07/01.

It will convert all values to yyyy/mm/dd form. Then you can convert data type to Date.

[image]
[image]